# Trying to align my buttons to take all the space in the container....only the bottom row is not doing it

Tags: button, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to align all my buttons in a row to make a mini personal project of a calculator to learn...however, because enter is longer, it is taking up more space.  How do I line up ALL the buttons?

```css
#entry {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black 2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  width: fit-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.calc-container {
  width: 20%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.row {
  background-color: grey;
}

.btn-primary {
  border-radius: 0;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

.btn-info {
  border-radius: 0;
  flex-grow: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My personal calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My personal calculator project!</h1>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="calc-container">
      <div class="row">
        <form name="calc">
          <input type="text" id="entry" </form>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">9</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">-</button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">+</button>

      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Enter</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

my html is here.  I am using the bootstrap flex box as well as the button elements here, i do not see any errors so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

-You just need to add `col-3` to all buttons as bootstrap work on `12-grid` system, so we can have `4 columns` of `col-3` ad `3*4=12`.

- I have also removed unnecessary css.

```css
#entry {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black 2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  width: fit-content;
}

.row {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My personal calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My personal calculator project!</h1>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="calc-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 px-0">
          <form name="calc">
            <input type="text" class="w-100" id="entry"> </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">9</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-info">-</button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-info">+</button>

      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-primary">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="col-3 btn btn-info">Enter</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```